# Selecting rows but disregarding repetition of cell values

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of customers that has repetition of first names and last names. I don't know what type of select query should I use to display specific row regarding their same entries.

Example:
Table: `customers`

```
customer_id|firstname|lastname
-----------+---------+---------
0000000001 |Peter    |Griffin
0000000002 |Peter    |Pan
0000000003 |Mary     |Magdalene
0000000003 |Mary     |Jane
```

And the output I want is like is:

```
customer_id|firstname|lastname
-----------+---------+---------
0000000001 |Peter    |Griffin
0000000003 |Mary     |Magdalene
```

I know this is easy but I'm new to SQL.

Comment: I suppose the 4th row should have `customer_id` 4 instead of 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (firstname)
       customer_id, firstname, lastname 
FROM   customers
ORDER  BY firstname, customer_id;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: I'll try this, Thanks! :)